# How to make my content stack horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how do i stack my drop-down and and the paragraph next to each other? I have tried by adding style float left. It didn't work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-right">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sel1">Select(select one):</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
          <option>Day</option>
          <option>Week</option>
          <option>Month</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <p>
        <label for="value">Value from 1 to 10:</label>
        <input type="text" id="value" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
      </p>
      <div id="slider"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `display: inline-block` for the elements to stack them horizontally. The default value for these elements are `display: block` which allows it to take up the entire width and wrap the next element to a new line.

```css
.form-group,
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pull-right">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1">Select(select one):</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
      <option>Day</option>
      <option>Week</option>
      <option>Month</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <p>
    <label for="value">Value from 1 to 10:</label>
    <input type="text" id="value" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```